# Neo4J create relationship hangs on EmbeddedDatabase

Tags: jakarta-ee, graph, neo4j, netbeans-7

I am using Neo4j 1.9.4 in EmbeddedDatabase mode and debugging the creation of nodes under NetBeans 7.4.

The following code however hangs at the creation of the relationship line, no error returned but debugging ends at that line, no warning or error in the NetBeans console.

I have therefore no way of debugging or understanding what's going on because nothing happens.

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try
{
     Node newNode = graphDb.createNode();
     newNode.setProperty("name", name);
     newNode.createRelationshipTo(parentNode, RelTypes.CHILD_OF);
     tx.success();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course newNode and parentNode are valid nodes and so the RelTypes.CHILD_OF.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

You need to finish the transaction.

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
    Node newNode = graphDb.createNode();
    newNode.setProperty("name", name);
    newNode.createRelationshipTo(parentNode, RelTypes.CHILD_OF);
    tx.success();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    tx.failure();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
```

Comment: you can probably omit the `catch` part. In this case the transaction will be rolled back and the exception bubbles up the stack.

Comment: Correct, I was just giving the example that I often see referenced in most documentation.

Comment: added the finish and same behaviour, without catch had already tried and same behaviour. One every 3 or four times it proceeds without issues. :(

Comment: the code is inside a function addNode(Node parentNode), could it be the node passed by value is the culpript? again anyway no error message or warning whatsoever.